# How to call to a servlet from jsp without scriptles?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to jsp and I have created jsp page to search something. I have written servlet as well. But I don't know hot to make the interaction between those.

My web.xml looks like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HotelSearch</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>it.testproject.HotelSearch</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HotelSearch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HotelSearch</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My servlet name is HotelSearch.java and Search page is Default.jsp and I want to redirect to SearchResults.jsp after the servlet call.

Can anyone expalain me how to do this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

step 1: load default.jsp i guess you have a form to submit the search query like

```
  <form method="post" action="HotelSearch">
  //action is your url pattern and method is your choice get or post
    // your text box
   </form>
```

step 2:  Now perform your business logic for search in your servlet
         then put your result data in request

```
 req.setAttribute("key",value); //value is object

 dispatch your request with data to `SearchResults.jsp` 
 req.getRequestDispatcher("SearchResults.jsp").forward(req,resp);
```

step 3: display data in `SearchResults.jsp` using req.getAttribute("key")

**Tip**

Best way is to configure  jsp file in web.xml

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>myjsp</servlet-name>
      <jsp-file>jsp/SearchResults.jsp</jsp-file>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>myjsp</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/jsp_url</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Now you can use

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("jsp_url").forward(req,resp);
```

Comment: What is the method runs after step1?

Comment: doPost() because method="post" , you can use method="get" then doGet()

Comment: It gives me an error "The requested resource is not available." What can I do? Do I need to copy my .class files to somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by proper mapping? My jsp files are under jsp folder in the root. then how can I map? And my Default page is outside the jsp folder.

Comment: Now you can map jsp file properly in web.xml

Answer (score 1):

So you would want to:

1. Use form to send data to servlet from first jsp:

   <form action="servlet_url">
       <input type="submit" ... >
   </form>
2. Redirect from servlet to second jsp:

   (HttpServletResponse)response.sendRedirect("jsp_url");

Comment: doPost. mahesh answer is more complete

Answer (score 1):

### On the Client

Make sure your  tag has the action set correctly:

```
<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<FORM action="${ctx}/HotelSearch">
    <input type="text" name="queryString">
</FORM>
```

### In the Servlet

response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/SearchResults.jsp");