# How can i retrieve data from Database using Java Server Page?

Tags: jsp

How can i retrieve data from Database using Java Server Page? Can anybody help me to know the concepts, because am a new one to work in Java Server Page.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734873/how-to-call-to-a-servlet-from-jsp-without-scriptles/23735208#23735208

Comment: First learn basics of JSP

Answer (score 2):

One can use the [sql tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_sql_query_tag.htm).

However often one sees a separation using [MVC, Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Where a servlet *(controller)* fills the data *(model)* in a request attribute, and forwards to a JSP *(view)*, that uses the resulting request attribute.

Then the JSP functons as a template and is more readable.

Comment: Direct [SQL] queries in views has to be one of the worst "features" of JSP/ASP :|

Comment: @user2864740: thanks for someone else saying that too. One would then use a JSP as one would use a PHP or ASP. For starters okay, as one always can program in a structured way. MVC is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

For beginner to java-ee i would recommend to read the tutorials of [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/quick/) which are very helpful and provides strong basics .

Apart from it you can find many basic examples in the below sites

- [**Tutorials Point**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/index.htm)
- [**javatpoint**](http://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp)
- [**Core servlets**](http://coreservlets.com)

And to your question [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/jdbc-tutorial) is the example. As @joop stated it very important to adhere MVC pattern

Hope this helps